# rendering anchor href with json2html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json2html

I am trying to render an anchor with json2html with the following transform:

```
'renderTimeline':[  {
    tag: "a",  
    class: "btn btn-warning btn-circle", 
    style: "float: right;", 
    html: "<i class=\"icon-remove\"></i>",
    "href": function() {
        var myhref = "javascript:delSchedule(" + this + ");";
        return myhref;
    }
}]
```

intention is to delete the json object,which is passed to it with :

```
$('#sunTimeLine').json2html(sched1.sunday, transforms.renderTimeline, {'events':true});
```

I get the following as o/p on the rendered html:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-circle" style="float: right;" href="javascript:delSchedule([object Object]);"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

when i click on the link(button) i get a message in browser console:

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: is there any other way to do this? may be on onclick event? a botton will also do instead of a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code solved my issue:

```
'renderTimeline':[  {
    tag: "a",  
    class: "btn btn-warning btn-circle", 
    style: "float: right;", 
    html: "<i class=\"icon-remove\"></i>",
    "onclick": function(e) {
       delSchedule(e);
   }}
}]
```

If I am passing the following json :

```
{ monday:[ { startTime:10:00, endTime: 12:00, room_id:cse124 }, { startTime:13:00, endTime: 15:00, room_id:lotus } ] }
```

I want to be able to access "monday" in the function delSchedule(). How do i do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to pass the reference of the clicked element to the `delSchedule` function, you need to change your `href` definition like this:

```
"href": function() {
    var myhref = "javascript:delSchedule(this);"; // note 'this' is part of the string, not concatenated
    return myhref;
}
```

Comment: no errors.
console displays: Empty string passed to getElementById().

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  tag: "a",  
  class: "btn btn-warning btn-circle", 
  style: "float: right;", 
  html: "<i class=\"icon-remove\"></i>",
  "href": function() {
      var myhref = "javascript:delSchedule(this);";
      return myhref;
    }
}
```

Comment: does not work, i guess since "this" is not being passed as an object.

Answer (score 0):

check the [documentation](http://json2html.com) for more examples but you should be using the built in jquery events like so

```
'renderTimeline':[  {
tag: "a",  
class: "btn btn-warning btn-circle", 
style: "float: right;", 
html: "<i class=\"icon-remove\"></i>",
"onclick": function(e) {
    delSchedule(this);
}}
}]
```

Note that json2html supports most jquery events by just adding the prefix "on" to the event .. eg onclick, onfocus, etc...

Comment: "this" returns the button node inside the delSchedule() function. confirmed by console.log() inside delSchedule() function.

What I need is the json piece passed to this transform; and is being rendered by this transform.

Comment: then use e.obj  .. more info at json2html.com => Attributes => jquery => Event Attributes